# Tomcat and Maven:Publishing failed with multiple errors Error reading file C:\Windows\System32

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a Tomcat v7.0 server setup in my eclipse (Neon) environment. I built the project and used Tomcat's add option to add the wars to the server. I am getting the following error since its unable to publish:

> Publishing failed Publishing failed with multiple errors
>    Error reading
>   file C:\Windows\System32\log4j\log4j\1.2.16\log4j-1.2.16.jar
>   C:\Windows\System32\log4j\log4j\1.2.16\log4j-1.2.16.jar (The system
>   cannot find the path specified)
>   Error reading file
>   C:\Windows\System32\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
>   C:\Windows\System32\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)
>     Error reading file
>   C:\Windows\System32\org\springframework\spring-context\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
>   C:\Windows\System32\org\springframework\spring-context\4.2.5.RELEASE\spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar
>   (The system cannot find the path specified) ...

and so on for bunch of other JARS

These are present in the Maven repository. I am not sure where its picking up this path.
I tried cleaning the working directory, checking the configuration file and reinstalling tomcat instance.

Has anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAVEN_HOME environment variable was not pointing to the right path. Worked after this was fixed.